# setting local variable with onSelect event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to create some local state changes before submitting the final state object to the server. I am first setting the user to targetUser, which is submitted to the redux store and the returned updated user with new role is held in local state. Once a user is a target user, I want a GradeSelect dropdown to be visible so the target user can be graded. Once the grade is selected, I'm currently trying to grab it as a data-id on the GradeSelect component submit button and add it to the local state object. From there I can submit the new user information (target user and grade) to the server.

I thought it would be easy to set a local variable (initialized by 'let') via an onSelect function. 
 Looks like this:

```
const GradeSelect = (props) => {
const { grades, userGrade, handleGradeChange } = props;
let newGrade = ''
const setGrade = (e) => newGrade = e.target.value;
return (
  <div>
  <select defaultValue={userGrade ? userGrade : "select"} onChange=
  {setGrade}>
    <option value="select" disabled>Select Grade</option>
    {
      grades.map(grade =>
        <option value={grade} key={grade}>{grade}</option>
      )
    }
  </select>
  <Button
    bsSize="xsmall"
    bsStyle="success"
    disabled={!newGrade.length}
    id={newGrade}
    onClick={handleGradeChange}>
      submit
  </Button>
  </div>
  );
};

export default GradeSelect;
```

handleGradeChange is simply this until I figure out why the newGrade isn't setting:

```
 handleGradeChange(e) {
  const grade = e.target.dataset.id
  console.log('NEW GRADE', grade)
}
```

GradeSelect is encompassed by this surrounding code with these as the options: let options = ["user", "targetUser"];

```
<td>
  <select
    onChange={handleRoleChange}
    data-id={JSON.stringify(user)}
    value={role}
   >
  <option value={role}>{role}</option>
     {
       role === options[0] ?
       <option value={options[1]}>{options[1]}</option> :
       <option value={options[0]}>{options[0]}</option>
     }
       </select>
     {
       role === options[1] ?
      <GradeSelect 
        grades={grades} 
        handleGradeChange={handleGradeChange} 
        userGrade={userGrade} 
       /> : null
      }
     </td>
```

In my research I thought it might be a binding of 'this' but 'this' is undefined in GradeSelect which is part of a larger component...I assume my issue is possibly there, but it is beyond me.

Here is a codePen I've made that illustrates the issue (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MrWXMo?editors=1111). I've had to create all of the imported props locally. I hope this doesn't affect the answer. However, the issue remains the same in the codePen.

This is my first question on stackOverflow so please forgive me for (and feel free to point out) what I've left out.

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: I didn't understand what the problem is but it's a bad practice to use global variables in React. Use state to save newGrade and control dropdown value.

Comment: @tugce yes I was trying to keep this a simple component instead of a class component. If it is not possible for what I'm trying to achieve then I will make it a class component and use local state to transfer the grade to the container component.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example using a component's local state.

```
const grades = ['Nothing', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];

class GradeSelect extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selected: 'Nothing'
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({selected: e.target.value});
  }

  onClick = (e) => {
    console.log(`onClick selected was ${this.state.selected}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <select value={this.state.selected} onChange={this.onChange}>
        {
          grades.map(g => <option key={g}>{g}</option>)
        }
        </select>
        <button
          onClick={this.onClick}
          disabled={this.state.selected === 'Nothing'}
        >
          submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
```

An example with a couple of communicating components.

```
const grades = ['Nothing', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'];

class GradeSelect extends React.PureComponent {
  static defaultProps = {
    onChange: () => {},
    value: 'Nothing',
    grades: []
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.props.onChange(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <select value={this.props.value} onChange={this.onChange}>
        {this.props.grades.map(g => <option key={g}>{g}</option>)}
      </select>
    );
  };
}

class GradeDashboard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    gradeA: 'Nothing',
    gradeB: 'Nothing'
  }

  onClick = (e) => {
    console.log(`onClick selected was ${this.state.gradeA} and ${this.state.gradeB}`);
  }

  onGradeAChange = (grade) => {
    this.setState({gradeA: grade});
  }

  onGradeBChange = (grade) => {
    this.setState({gradeB: grade});
  }

  anyUnselected = () => {
    return this.state.gradeA === 'Nothing' ||
           this.state.gradeB === 'Nothing';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <GradeSelect grades={grades} value={this.state.gradeA} onChange={this.onGradeAChange} />
        <GradeSelect grades={grades} value={this.state.gradeB} onChange={this.onGradeBChange}/>
        <button
          onClick={this.onClick}
          disabled={this.anyUnselected()}
        >
          submit
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```